# can anybody please explain me the answer for Putnam Exam $2010 A-3$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, contest-math, partial-derivative

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ylgg.png)

How was $(x,y)$ transformed into $(au-bv,bu+av)$? and how did $∂g$ become $∂x$ and $∂y$?

Comment: ?? It didn't!  g is the function being differentiated, x and y are the independent variables.  Do you mean "how did differentiation with respect to u become differentiating with respect to u and v" then it is the "chain rule". If f is a function of u and v and u and v are themselves functions of x and y, then we can think of f as a function of x and y and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Via the Chain Rule:
$$\dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial u} = \dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial x}\cdot\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}+ \dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial y}\cdot\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

Now because $x=au-bv$, then $\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u}=a$ , and similarly for $y = bu+av$

$$\dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial u} = a\dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial x}+ b\dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial y}$$

Then just substitute $g(u,v) = h(x,y)$

$$\dfrac{\partial g(u,v)}{\partial u} = a\dfrac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial x}+ b\dfrac{\partial h(x,y)}{\partial y}$$

Everything else depends on missing details not included in the clipping.  What is $h(x,y)$?

$\Box$

---

We have $\mathbf (u,v\mathbf ) = k^{-1}~\mathbf (ax+by, -ax+by\mathbf )$ where $k=a^2+b^2 ~\neq 0$.

So $(a^2+b^2)~\mathbf (u,v\mathbf ) = \mathbf (ax+by, -bx+ay\mathbf )$

Then $(a^2+b^2)~\mathbf (au,bv\mathbf ) = \mathbf (a^2x+aby, -b^2x+aby\mathbf )$ and $(a^2+b^2)~\mathbf (bu,av\mathbf ) = \mathbf (abx+b^2y, -abx+a^2y\mathbf )$

So $(a^2+b^2)(au-bv)=(a^2+b^2)x$ and $(a^2+b^2)(bu+av)=(a^2+b^2)y$

Thusly :$$\mathbf (x,y\mathbf ) = \mathbf (au-bv, bu+av\mathbf )$$

$\Box\Box$

Comment: h(x,y)=a∂h(x,y)/∂x+b∂h(x,y)/∂y

Comment: how can you type fractions...

Comment: http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2010.pdf

Comment: And how did the linear transformation part work out?

Comment: @user330984 It is just an application of linear algebra

Comment: Also $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ is `\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}`.  Use `\dfrac` for displaystyle fractions and `\tfrac` for tiny fractions.  $\dfrac 1 3$ versus $\tfrac 1 3$

Comment: I really appreciate your help, man!

Comment: By the way, last question, can't I prove this question by simply saying partial derivatives equal zero when $h(x,y)$ attains maximum/minimum, which is M/-M, so $h(x,y)$ has to equal zero when it reaches M . Thus both its upper and lower bound is zero, Q.E.D?

Answer (score 0):

?? It didn't!  g is the function being differentiated, x and y are the independent variables.  Do you mean "how did differentiation with respect to u become differentiating with respect to u and v" then it is the "chain rule". If f is a function of u and v and u and v are themselves functions of x and y, then we can think of f as a function of x and y and  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$

Comment: That makes sense. Could you please also explain me the linear transformation part?